# mPDF Text rotation

Tags: php, mpdf

I am trying to rotate / angle text using mpdf. But I could not find any parameter to do so. here is my code

```
 $mpdf->WriteFixedPosHTML('Date Today', 98, 102, 50, 90, 'auto');
```

Here I able to set text position based on my expectation. But I could not rotate it. I am using laravel framework. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I read [the documentation](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/writefixedposhtml.html) correctly you can do this:

```
$html = '<span style="position:absolute;rotate:90;">Date Today</span>';
$mpdf->WriteFixedPosHTML($html, 98, 102, 50, 90, 'auto');
```

See: [Fixed position blocks](https://mpdf.github.io/what-else-can-i-do/fixed-position-blocks.html)

Comment: Thanks for reply but it's not rotating the text

Comment: @Mithun It says: _"Applies only to block elements with position fixed or absolute"_. I changed my answer, can you try that? I was assuming the `WriteFixedPosHTML()` would have made it "absolute". Sorry, I cannot test this myself, but I believe this is the way to rotate text.

Comment: Thanks for giving your time. Still  it's not rotating

Comment: Text in fixed/absolute elements can be rotated 90|-90 ° only. https://mpdf.github.io/css-stylesheets/supported-css.html

Comment: @Finwe: Can you explain your remark? What needs to be changed?

Comment: rotate:45 will not work, only 90 or -90 values are acceptable.

Comment: @Finwe Ah, that makes sense. I read it as "between 90 and -90", but the "|" could be a "or".

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example with a custom page size and a rotated div.

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf([
    'mode' => 'utf-8',
    'format' => [50, 25],
    'margin_left' => 0,
    'margin_right' => 0,
    'margin_top' => 0,
    'margin_bottom' => 0,
    'margin_header' => 0,
    'margin_footer' => 0
]);
$html = '<div style="position: fixed; bottom: 0; rotate: -90; text-align: center; width: 25mm;">
    Text
    <br>
    Text #2
</div>';
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
$mpdf->Output();
```